# Mocking and testing onError with parameters

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

I am trying to mock useMutation, It has a certain parameter called onError. I am using it as depicted in the piece of code right below.

Whenever useRedirectOnErrorMutation is used, a header with the token is attached to the request, so if the token is invalid there will be 401 error response which I will catch in the onError function that comes with useMutation and redirect the user to the login page.

```
export const useRedirectOnErrorMutation = <
    TData = unknown,
    TError = unknown,
    TVariables = void,
    TContext = unknown
>(
    redirectionPath: string,
    key: MutationKey,
    mutationFunction: MutationFunction<TData, TVariables>,
    options?: UseMutationOptions<TData, TError, TVariables, TContext>
): UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables, TContext> => {
    const router = useRouter();
    console.log(useMutation);
    return useMutation(key, mutationFunction, {
        ...options,
        onError: (error) => {
            if (error?.response.status == "401" || error?.response.status == "422") {
                localStorage.removeItem("token");
                localStorage.removeItem("userId");
                router.push(redirectionPath);
            }
        },
    });
};
```

The above code works perfectly fine, now I have to test this function with 100% coverage.

My current implementation on the testing of the function is as follows.

```
describe("(when api call gives error", () => {
        it("should return the response", () => {
            const push = jest.fn();

            let onError: (
                error: any,
                variables: any,
                context: any | undefined
            ) => Promise<void> | void;
            // @ts-ignore
            Router.useRouter = jest.fn(() => ({
                push: push,
            }));
            const mockData = { email: "test@test.com", password: "test@1234" };

            // @ts-ignore
            ReactQuery.useMutation = jest.fn(
                (
                    key: MutationKey,
                    mutationFunction: MutationFunction,
                    options: MutateOptions<
                        AxiosResponse<LoginResponse>,
                        AxiosError,
                        LoginValidationValues
                    >
                ) => {
                    console.log(options.onError.arguments);
                    onError = options.onError;
                    return {
                        mutate: jest.fn(() => mockData),
                        isLoading: false,
                    };
                }
            );
            const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() =>
                useRedirectOnErrorMutation("/auth/admin/login", "key", adminLoginAPI)
            );

            rerender();

            act(() => {
                onError({}, {}, {});
            });

            expect(result.current.mutate(mockData)).toEqual(mockData);
            expect(push).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Now, the issue with testing here is that everytime I run it, it still shows the onError part uncovered and an error message saying that error.response is not defined.
I am not sure how to pass the onError parameters in the testing.

That is **(error)**

```
onError: (error) => {
                if (error?.response.status == "401" || error?.response.status == "422") {
                    localStorage.removeItem("token");
                    localStorage.removeItem("userId");
                    router.push(redirectionPath);
                }
```

Ideally passing an error object in the testing wrapped by act should have worked but it also ended up with an error message **onError is not a function**.

```
act(()=>{
  onError({response:{status: 401}},{},{})
})
```

Any help would be appreciated! I am completely stuck here.

Comment: please rephrase your question. what is working, what is not working? how is it behaving, how would you expect it to behave?

Comment: I have made the changes! I hope this gives more insight. My apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really give you a specific answer, just maybe a bit of advice:

1. what is the purpose behind the need to have 100% test coverage? The function you are trying to test has many side effects, and you have to mock things like the request, localStorage, react-router, onError, ... and what remains is basically more testing code than actual production code. You are basically testing if react-query calls the `onError` method, and this is something that `react-query` tests internally. Don't test 3rd party code - test your own code. Things like this are much better tested with integration or end to end tests, [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) is a great tool for that.
2. If you want to test custom hooks, I would only mock the result of the queryFn, *not* the whole mutation function. [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) is good for that - there is even an example of how to to this in the [react-query-docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/testing#testing-network-calls). [mock-service-worker](http://mswjs.io/) is a great tool to mock requests on the network level, and I have recently written an article about testing react query with mock service worker if you want to give it a read [here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/testing-react-query). It also links to an example repo with working tests.

Comment: But then how do I know for sure that when an error is encountered, the page will be redirected from the testing perspective?

Also, I need 100% coverage because we have a pipeline that fails if the testing is not 95% above. The point being, it encourages us to maintain code quality and handle edge cases.

Also, assuming that when I mock the API response and send a 401 error, the onError part will be executed and it won't have the error object to check the status from.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to turn off react retries when creating query client in tests otherwise react-query will wait for next retry failures (default : 3 times) and it will likely timeout. https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/2196#discussioncomment-659468